# Find the sample space for a committee of two chosen from Alice

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics

Find the sample space for a committee of two chosen from Alice (A), Bill (B), Carol (C), and David (D).

{(A, B), (A, D), (B, C), (C, D)}

{(A, B), (C, D

{(A, B), (A, C), (A, D), (B, C), (B, D), (C, D)}

{A, B, C, D}

my choice is --> {(A, B), (A, C), (A, D), (B, C), (B, D), (C, D)}

Find the sample space if both sexes must be represented.

{(A, B), (A, C), (A, D), (B, C), (B, D), (C, D)}

{(A, B), (C, D)}

{A, B, C, D}

{(A, B), (A, D), (B, C), (C, D)}

my choice is ----> {(A, B), (C, D)}

is that correct ???

Comment: the first one is correct but the second one must have 4 - elements

Comment: do you mean this --> $${{A, B, C, D}}$$

Comment: no, I am refering to the last option

Answer (score 2):

If you have not already studied 'combinations', you will soon
learn that the number of elements in the first sample space
is ${4 \choose 2} = \frac{4!}{2!\,2!} = 6.$ Your correct
first answer has six elements.

To find the answer to the second question, look at the sample
space for the first one, and get rid of the outcomes that do
not have one person of each sex. (Any time you impose a fresh
restriction, the number of outcomes may decrease.)